# What is the role of `to_s` method on `x`?

Tags: ruby

This code will generate a positive even integer ladder:

```
puts "Enter an integer"
n = gets
def pattern(n)
  2.step(n, 2).map {|x| x.to_s * x}.join("\n")
end
```

I have been struggling to figure out what `to_s` does to the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you looked at [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) to understand what `to_s` does with integers? Please look there first before asking. It really is that simple.

Answer (score 0):

It converts a fixnum into a string. It is particularly necessary because it is followed by the `* x` operation, which multiplies a string. If `to_s` had not been applied, then `* x` will multiply the fixnum arithmetically.

Answer (score 0):

The `x.to_s` is needed so that String's `*` method is called and not Integer's `*` method.

```
> i = 2
=> 2
> i * 2
=> 4
> s = '2'
=> "2"
> s * 2
=> "22"
```